# django user model - get other custom fields

Tags: python, django, relational-database, django-related-manager

I am stuck.

I have a user model which is subclass of django's user model.

and I have other tables which relate to my user model.

I wanted to get some values from those tables, it says:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'users_bewertung'
```

my code is:

```
    _username = request.POST.get('username_login')
    pwd = request.POST.get('pwd_login')
    user = authenticate(username=_username, password=pwd)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            ratings = user.users_bewertung.all()
            #...
```

`users_bewertung` is the related name of a reference field of table `Bewertung` to Table `User`:

```
von_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="users_bewertung")
```

how can i access those information via related manager?

**EDIT**: my model.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User(User):
  registerdate = models.CharField(max_length=400,default='')    
  foto = models.ImageField(upload_to="user/",default='')    
  uniq_hashed = models.CharField(max_length=400,default='')
  kennwort = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='')
  confirmed = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='')
```

Comment: Do you login your subclass or the Django user?

Comment: @limelights ``authenticate()`` is from django's model. so this means i am logging django user in, right? honestly i didnot know the difference during login. i thought, I just login django user and get subclass fields via django user instance, cannot i do it?

Comment: Nope, it's not that magical :) It doesn't traverse down in the inheritance chain automatically. So what you need to do is `custom_user = CustomUserModel.objects.get(user=user)`.

Comment: could you show your model definitions?

Comment: @limelights, oh okay, but what do i do during register? during register, i am saving username,pwd and email to django user and other fieds by doing this: 
``user = User.objects.create_user(username,email,pwd)``, 
``user.otherfield = value`` etc. here ``User`` is django user. should this be my custom User?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be `user.bewertung.users_bewertung`?

Try going into the shell and using `dir()` on the user:

```
python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
usrs = User.objects.all()
dir(usrs[0])
```

It should show you the available methods for that user.  You should be able to use something like this to discover the correct method.

You might be able to narrow it down better with an `__isnull` filter on the users:

```
usrs = User.objects.filter(bewertung__isnull=False)
dir(usrs[0])
```

### Update

Perhaps you need to try `_set`:

```
ratings = user.users_bewertung_set.all()
```

or

```
ratings = user.bewertung_set.all()
```

### Another Possibility

Perhaps the problem is that the Bewertung model doesn't have the user that you are logging in.  Perhaps you need to check if it exists, before referencing the model:

```
if user.is_active:
    login(request, user)
    if hasattr(user, 'users_bewertung'):
        ratings = user.users_bewertung.all()
```

Comment: A Gotcha is that when doing `dir(usrs[0])` since he inherits from Django's User model he'll get all of User's methods as well.

Comment: @doniyor could you post your model definitions, please?

Comment: @doniyor Name it something else instead of `User`. I think that'll work then.

Comment: @limelights, ok but i still need to save all data to custommodel, right? so what is the use of django model then?

Comment: @doniyor have you read this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @limelights That's not much of a gotcha.

Comment: I updated the answer.  Have you tried using `dir` on the user to see what methods are available? @doniyor

Comment: @bozdoz, yeah, i did, i see only methods of django's user model

Comment: updated again. perhaps you should query the Bewertung model to see if the user exists: `Bewertung.objects.get(user=user)` @doniyor

Comment: @bozdoz, okay, let me try this

Comment: @bozdoz, if user athenticated, which user is in session? django user or my custom? i am really stuck? do you think, i should read the whole docs for it first?

Comment: Isn't the custom user an addition to the django user?  They should be the same thing I think.  Why not print out user.id to see which user is being authenticated.  Then get that users information with `User.objects.get(id=whatever_number_you_get)`

Comment: @bozdoz, now i found that there is method called get_profile() which gives me the user profile which is bound to django's user. now i authenticate the django user and get the userprofile which is my custom user model.